# What makes spin 1/2 anyons special?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, condensed-matter, topology, topological-field-theory, anyons

If the spectrum of a TQFT contains a fermion, the theory becomes a spin-TQFT, and it depends on the spin structure of the manifold (cf. [1505.05856](https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.05856)). On the other hand, if no such anyon exists, the TQFT can be formulated without specifying such structure.

This seems very unintuitive to me, because the spectrum of a generic TQFT, spin or otherwise, contains anyons whose spin take rational values from zero to one. In other words, we may find bosons (spin $0$), semions (spin $1/4$), fermions (spin $1/2$), and essentially any other rational value (e.g., $7/11$, $2/5$, etc.).

I understand that in $d\ge4$, the spin can *only* take integer and half-integer values, and therefore the fermionic particles *are* special. But in $d=3$, where all spins are allowed, fermions seem to lose their special status. Why would a theory containing spins $\{0,1/3,3/7\}$ be independent of the spin structure, but it suddenly depends on it if you include the number $1/2$? It seems to me that the number $1/2$ is the "least weird" one in the zoo of fractional spins. Yet it is precisely this number what changes the theory from a TQFT to a spin-TQFT. What makes spin 1/2 anyons special, as opposed to anyons of other rational spins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your premise is faulty. It is simply not true that a TQFT becomes a spin TQFT simply because it contains a fermionic excitation. There are many counterexamples -- the simplest would be $\mathbb{Z}_2$ gauge theory (the low energy theory of the toric code). However, note that these are *emergent* fermions in a system whose *microscopic* degrees of freedom are purely bosonic. (One consequence of this is that these fermions are never "transparent" -- there is always an excitation in the theory which braids non-trivially with the fermion).

Where spin TQFTs do arise in physics is in describing systems whose *microscopic* degrees of freedom are fermionic (for example, topological phases of electrons). The difference here is that the fermions are transparent -- there are no excitations which they braid non-trivially with. Note that fermions and bosons are the only particles which can be transparent, because if an Abelian anyon $x$ has topological spin $\theta$, then moving an $x$ particle all the way around another $x$ particle picks up phase $\theta^2$, and only fermions ($\theta = -1$) and bosons ($\theta = +1$) have $\theta^2 = 1$.

Comment: Ah, perfect. Clear and succinct. Cheers!